# GWTP (Java): Apply CSS style on div element

Tags: java, css, gwt, gwtp

I am using GWTP and I am trying to include `boxcontainer` style in a div element. However, it is not working. Seems that the CSS is not properly link? Any ideas? Thanks

**resources/Thumbnail.css**

```
.boxcontainer {
  width:100%;
  height:900px;
  border:0px solid #000;
  padding-top:20px;
padding-bottom:5px;
padding-right:15px;
padding-left:15px;
margin: 0px auto -1px auto; 
   background: #000000;
}
```

**Thumbnail.ui.xml (HTML template)**

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
    xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'>
<ui:with field="res" type="com.gw.aaaa.client.presenter.dashboard.ThumbnailResources"/>
    <div ui:field='container' class="{res.style.boxcontainer}"></div>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

**ThumbnailResources.java**

```
public interface ThumbnailResources extends ClientBundle {
public static final ThumbnailResources INSTANCE =  GWT.create(ThumbnailResources.class);
@Source("resources/Thumbnail.css")
ThumbnailStyle style();
}
```

**ThumbnailStyle.java**

```
public interface ThumbnailStyle extends CssResource {
    String boxcontainer();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to inject that your styles in order to be referenced. Use:

```
ThumbnailResources.INSTANCE.style().ensureInjected();
```

Only when using `<ui:style>` the generated `CssResource` is also automatically injected. With `<ui:with>` you are referencing an external `CssResource`, but you need to take care to inject it (and of course to instantiate the relative `ClientBundle` as you already did).

Comment: Thanks Andrea. I just tried including that line in the Thumbnail.java but it returns FALSE...

Comment: Post `Thumbnail.java`, or at least constructor and fields. Chances are you are not calling it in the right place (i.e., *before* `createAndBindUi()` call).

Comment: Are you sure this line is correct? <div ui:field='container' class="{res.style.boxcontainer}"></div>

Comment: You can [very well](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder#Hello_World) have `Element`-based templates.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

`<div ui:field='container' class="{res.style.boxcontainer}">`

just use:

```
<div ui:field='container' styleName="boxcontainer">
```